# Move top menu bar to left side in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, topmenu

I want to move the top menu bar to left sidebar I have written this code

```
<move element="catalog.topnav" destination="header-wrapper" after="block-search"/>
```

Through this code it is moving in header now, I want to know what to write in destination to move it to left side?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: <move element="top.search" destination="catalog.topnav" after="-" />

Comment: Left side means ? Do you have any left sidebar for all of your pages ?

Comment: no that category menu is coming on the top i want it on left side as vertical

Comment: @AshishRamchandani Have achieved this? I also needed same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try This

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
  <move element="catalog.topnav" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo"/>
</body>
```